# Calling eclipsec.exe to install p2 plugin using python and subprocess.call

Tags: python, eclipse, subprocess, p2

```
import subprocess
print ("this is test installer")
program = "C:\\ti\\ccsv6\\eclipse\\eclipsec.exe"
command1 = "-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -uninstallIU        org.eclipse.(...).feature.group -destination C:\ti\ccsv6\eclipse -profile epp.package.cpp -noSplash"
command_run = subprocess.call([program,command1])
```

This is the code I'm currently running to uninstall a plugin, and this particular line would work in command prompt. However if I use python, it would open eclipse and would not execute, and give me the error 
dvtLogOptions.xml DOES NOT exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two issues:

1. `command1` has unescaped `'\t'` in it. '\t' is a tab in Python -- a single character. If you want two characters (the backslash and `t` instead) then escape the backslash: `'\\t'` or use a raw string literal `r'\t'` e.g.:

   ```
   program = r'C:\ti\ccsv6\eclipse\eclipsec.exe'
   ```
2. If you pass a list then it should be exactly one command-line argument per item: `[command, 'arg1', 'arg 2', '...']`. On Windows, you could pass the command as a string:

   ```
   subprocess.check_call(r'C:\ti\ccsv6\eclipse\eclipsec.exe '
       r'-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -uninstallIU ...\t...')
   ```